# Adjust Fairness in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I adjust fairness between given k threads to generate some output?
In other words imagine we have k threads printing "1" and n threads printing "2".
Now how can we put fairness between threads so each thread print(for example "1") as much as other (k - 1) print(for example "1").and the same for n thread printing "2".

Comment: i think i must handle it wit wait and notify method but i don not know how?

Answer (score 1):

Before you create the threads, create an array[0..numThreads-1] of empty semaphores, one for each thread you are going to create.  Signal to each thread on its creation an incrementing semaphore index, 0..numThreads-1.

In the thread function, have it wait on its semaphore[index], then print something, then signal the [(index+1) mod numThreads] semaphore, then loop round to wait on the semaphore[index] again.

Once you have done that, nothing should happen at all.

Throw in one semaphore unit, anywhere.

Comment: can u explain a little more about it?

Comment: It's esentially passing a 'print token' around the threads.  When a thread has printed something, it passes the token to the next and this continues in a circular fashion.

Comment: i just want to know exactly where to wait() and where to notify the thread to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

well, I understand a little, you could make that a thread print a number if you send that number to their constructor.
for example:

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread 
{ 
   int number = 0;
   public MyThread(int number) {
      this.number = number;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   { 
      while(true) {
         System.out.println(this.number); 
         this.sleep(1000);//control exception
      }
   }

}
```

then in your main

```java
public class Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int k = 10
       for(int i = 0; i < k; k++) {
          MyThread mt = new MyThread(1);
          mt.start();
          mt.join();
       }
    }
}
```

You should repeat a similar form for Thread printing 2